# Namespace Scope Question

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a quick question about namespace scope:

1. I have two namespaces, A and B, where B is nested inside A.
2. I declare some typedefs inside A.
3. I declare a class inside B ( which is inside A )

To access the typedefs (declared in A), from inside B, do I need to do "using namespace A;"

ie:

B.hpp:

```
using namespace A;

namespace A {
namespace B {

  class MyClass {

    typedeffed_int_from_A a;
  };

}
}
```

This seems redundant... Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To access the typedefs (declared in A), from inside B, do I need to do "using namespace A;"

No.

---

However if there is a typedef or some other symbol with same name as your typedef, defined in the namespace `B`, then you need to write this:

```
A::some_type a;
```

Lets do a simple experiment to understand this.

Consider this code: (**must read the comments**)

```
namespace A
{
   typedef int some_type; //some_type is int

   namespace B
   {
        typedef char* some_type;  //here some_type is char*

        struct X
        {
               some_type     m; //what is the type of m? char* or int?
               A::some_type  n; //what is the type of n? char* or int?
        };

        void f(int) { cout << "f(int)" << endl; }
        void f(char*) { cout << "f(char*)" << endl; }
   }
}

int main() {
        A::B::X x;
        A::B::f(x.m);
        A::B::f(x.n);
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
f(char*)
f(int)
```

That proves that *type* of `m` is `char*` and *type* of `n` is `int` as expected or intended.

Online Demo : http://ideone.com/abXc8

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't need a `using` directive; as `B` is nested inside of `A`, the contents of `A` are in scope when inside `B`.